# how do i extract data from string (php) using preg_match?

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching, preg-match

I have a string,

```
   DXD RO 012345 SMITH JOHN 094 5251 907 REQ 008313 M
```

I am trying to extract the phone number, which might have 5-15 digits, with unknown amount of white spaces. Also i need the last letter (sex) and the first name.

what is the exact pattren to do so ?

Comment: Have you tried something yourself? There's no general answer for this, unless we can see the specification for this data format. It's easy to give you a specific regex for this specific text sample, but I'll guess the text will be changing, so the answer may or may not be applicable for your actual case.

Comment: i have tried few things myself, but since im new with php, i failed them all. i know that what im trying to do is possible in c. 
the data format is pretty constant: 
[word] ,whitespace, [word] ,whitespace, [number] ,whitespace [name(may contain few whitespaces)], whitespace, [phone-number(may contain whitespaces) ] ,whiespace, [word] , whitespace, [number], whitespace, [char]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$subject = "DXD RO 012345 SMITH JOHN 094 5251 907 REQ 008313 M";
$pattern = "/[a-z]+\s+[a-z]+\s+\d+\s+[^\d]+\s*(\d+\s*\d+\s*\d+)\s+[a-z\-]+\s+\d+\s+([a-z])/i";

preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
```

$matches[1] contains the telephone number and $matches[2] contains the sex.

For this, I assumed that columns 1,2,4,5 and 9 only contain letters, and 3,6,7,8,10 only digits(the sex has to be a letter).

However, if you need to have digits as well as letters, just replace **[a-z]** or **\d** with **[a-z0-9]** for the respective column(**\s** is whitespace)

Comment: This regex is way too specific. *"might have 5-15 digits, with unknown amount of white spaces"*...

Comment: I have modified it a little, so it fits the specs. Thanks

Comment: thx alot Vlad, it works at 99% of the cases, exept those which have a word with the char '-' at the 9th column word, is '-' a special char ?

Comment: It's just that the regex is built that way. I have edited it so it works even when there is a dash in the 9th column. This is why deceze asked for some data, we must know what range of characters each column will hold.

Comment: thx alot, u really helped me understand how the pattren-matching works.

Answer (score 0):

For phone You can try:

```
$subject = "DXD RO 012345 SMITH JOHN 094 5251 907 REQ 008313 M";
preg_match_all("/([0-9]|\s).+{5,15}(\s)/si", $subjectt, $matches);
```